# How to solve basic Electrostatic question using "method of images"?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, method-of-images

Two conducting planes, intersecting at right-angles to each other, are kept at a potential phi. Calculate the potential at a point in space if the total charge on a plane of area(alpha) be Q.

[image]

This is my working, can anyone tell me whether my 2nd boundary condition is logically sound or not? my confusion is generally the charge distb in such problems are not known, but when it is known is the below solution the correct way to do it?

Comment: You should provide an attempt at a solution otherwise we have no idea what is keeping you from getting the solution yourself.

Comment: @Triatticus added my working as an edit.